# Get Class fields from annotated Object in annotation processor

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, annotation-processing, java-annotations

i'm working on my first annotation processor. I'm trying to get fields of class through annotation on declared object(that is a field of a method). 
For example:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
}

...
public void myMethod(@MyAnnotation Person person) { 
    /*...*/
}
...
```

Through @MyAnnotation i want to get 'name' and 'surname' fields.

Is that possible? I did something of similar with method's field:

```
...
for (Element element : roundEnvironment.getElementsAnnotatedWith(AnnotationOnMethod.class)) {
    ExecutableElement method = (ExecutableElement) element;
    List<? extends VariableElement> parameters = method.getParameters();
    parameters.forEach(p -> {
        /*code here for parameter*/
    });
}
...
```

Thanks in advance, Luca.

Solution: 
For my solution i am assuming that the annotation is on method and not on method's parameter. The correct answer to my question is the answer posted by rjeeb. You can see it below.

```
Set<? extends Element> elements = roundEnvironment.getElementsAnnotatedWith(AnnotationOnMethod.class);
for (Element element : elements) {
    ExecutableElement executableElement = (ExecutableElement) element; 
    List<? extends VariableElement> parameters = executableElement.getParameters();
    for (VariableElement parameter : parameters) {
        DeclaredType declaredType = (DeclaredType) parameter.asType();
        TypeElement clazz = (TypeElement) declaredType.asElement();
        clazz.getEnclosedElements().forEach(o -> {
                if (o.getKind().isField()) {
                    log.info("Simple name of field: " + o.getSimpleName());
                }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your annotation is of type `ElementType.PARAMETER` so once you get the element that annotated with it then it should be `TypeElement` and therefore you can get the fields of this type element

```
for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(AnnotationOnMethod.class)) {
    TypeElement typeElement = elementUtils.getTypeElement(element.asType().toString());
    Set<? extends Element> fields = typeElement.getEnclosedElements()
            .stream()
            .filter(o -> o.getKind().isField())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    // do something with the fields
}
```

you can get the helper classes from the `AbstractProcessor`

```
private Messager messager;
private Types typeUtils;
private Elements elementUtils;

@Override
public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {
    messager = processingEnv.getMessager();
    typeUtils = processingEnv.getTypeUtils();
    elementUtils = processingEnv.getElementUtils();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, can you tell me the package of "elementUtils" on you example? I cannot resolve it in my code. Anyway i resolved my problem, i will update this post :D

Comment: Thanks, your answer is really useful. I didn't know about that utilities. I will test your code to check if it works. If the code works i will accept the answer as solution. I edited this post, if you want let's check my solution :)

Comment: The only difference between my solution and yours is that you are assuming that the annotation will be in the method and not on method parameters

Comment: Yes, right. I just tested your code and it works like charm. Is good solution, thanks.

Comment: One word of caution: if your annotation processor is re-running incrementally, changes made to the `Person` class won't necessarily  cause your processor to re-run, since your annotation is on the `myMethod` member, presumably in another class. Consider annotating the `Person` also so your annotation processor monitors changes there, or else advise your users that this may not work in gradle/eclipse/etc.